# How to sign dlls in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, sign

I've got a project in visual studio which has 2 dlls with the same simple name and when I compile the solution I get the error:

```
An assembly with the same simple name 'Interop.ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side.
```

I tried going to the project's properties to the signing option and assign a strong name but that just created other errors since I have other solution's projects referenced and they don't have a string name but I can't change their properties.
I hoped that changing the name of the dll files would help but it didn't.

So how can I actually sign the 2 dlls or how can I change one of the file's simple name so I can compile the solution?